# RegEx to Extract Multiple Choice Questions

Tags: regex

I have 24 exams in a plain text file with 50 MC questions each plus a bunch of other stuff.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to capture:

**1 Studying oral histories, archaeological evidence, and cultural histories are methods most often used by 
(1) 
economists (3) philosophers 
(2) 
anthropologists (4) political scientists**

I'd like to capture the stem and the 4 answer choices for each question, or at the very least, just the stems.

**How do I get it so the regex captures everything from the digit (question number) all the way up to, but not including, the first open parenthesis of the first answer choice?**

So far, I have: \d{1,2}\s

Comment: And why RegEx? I think something based on index, split and substring would be more fitting for this.

Comment: @bjornars I was gonna say the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Potential Regex:

```
^\d{1,2}\s([^\(]*)
```

Explanation:
 ^ (beginning line) that starts with 1 or 2 digits and a space. Capture everything up to the first parenthesis. This is a basic regex, and assumes there are no other parenthesis in the question aside from the answer numbers. Meaning it will not work for the following example:

**20 My question (not yours) has the following elements: (1) adverb (2) pronoun (3) all of the above (4) none of the above**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl script that do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = q/1 Studying oral histories, archaeological evidence (of course), and cultural histories are methods most often used by (1) economists (3) philosophers (2) anthropologists (4) political scientists/;

my ($question, @answers) = $str =~ /^\d+ (.*?) (?:\(\d\))(.*?) (?:\(\d\))(.*?) (?:\(\d\))(.*?) (?:\(\d\))(.*?)$/;
say $question;
say Dumper \@answers;
```

**output:**

```
Studying oral histories, archaeological evidence (of course), and cultural histories are methods most often used by
$VAR1 = [
          ' economists',
          ' philosophers',
          ' anthropologists',
          ' political scientists'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{1,2}\s.*?)(\(\d{1,2}\)\s.*?)+$
```

I think that will capture the entire question and answer set, grouping the answers (and including the question/answer numbers inside the groups). The `.*?` means the `*` will be lazy, so it should stop before consuming the next answer.

If you only want the question, you could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(\d{1,2}\s.*?)(?=\s\(\d{1,2}\))
```

I should mention that both of these allow for parentheses inside the question/answer text, as long as they don't contain just a number (i.e. `(1)` form).

Comment: I've chosen to include the numbers inside the groups, but that can be changed. Let me know if you'd prefer to omit them.